How to Program a Dynamic Component Using Steps with PrimeVue 3.53?
I'm trying to implement a dynamic component using the Steps component from PrimeVue 3.53. My goal is to have each step dynamically selected based on the user's choices in the previous step.
Here's a simplified example of what I want to achieve:

Step 1


If the user selects Option_1, then show Step_A.
If the user selects Option_2, then show Step_B.


Step 2


Continue with subsequent steps based on user selections.

How can I program this using PrimeVue's Steps component? I would appreciate a code example or guidance on how to achieve this dynamic behavior.
